# How to parse json data with dynamically changing keys in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a json object with dynamically changing key that is provided with the last element of the list item. Based on this keyList I have to map the json response. How can I parse this type of json object?

Json response:

Eg:1

```
[
 {"ABC":100, "BVBV":200,"NBN":87,"MNM":09},
 {"ABC":1004, "BVBV":90,"NBN":847,"MNM":049},
 {"ABC":1040, "BVBV":2050,"NBN":867,"MNM":079},

 {"overallScore":10000,"keyList":"ABC,BVBV,NBN,MNM"}
]
```

Eg:2

```
 [
  {"PQR":100, "XYZ":200,"POI":87,"IOK":09,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},
  {"PQR":1004, "XYZ":90,"POI":847,"IOK":049,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},
  {"PQR":1040, "XYZ":2050,"POI":867,"IOK":079,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},

  {"overallScore":10000,"keyList":"PQR,XYZ,POI,IOK,LOP,MLP"}
]
```

Json key is based on the last element in the json response.

Here is the expected json mapping,

```
{
value1 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[0]],
value2 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[1]],
value3 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[2]],
value4 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[3]],
value5 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[4]],
..............
...............
...........
},

{
value1 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[0]],
value2 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[1]],
value3 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[2]],
value4 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[3]],
value5 = json[json['keyList'].split(',')[4]],
..............
...............
...........
},
......
```

List of keys will be changed randomly.

Comment: Please give us an example showing what you want.

Comment: Question edited..

Comment: The Json example you have posted is not valid Json.

Comment: Also, is it intended the keys in your Json example are with capital letter and the `keys` list is not?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: So you want `value1` to always be the value of the first entry in `keyList`? So if `keyList` was  e.g. `"keyList":"key5,key1,key2,key3,key4"` then you want `value1` to be 500?

Comment: Exactly, and also key list may differ to key6, key7, etc...

Comment: Ok, but the keys in `keyList` does always exists in the Json?

Comment: I should also note that the Json are still not valid. `[]` means list but you have added key-value pairs which are used for maps. So It is still not possible to parse the provided Json example since it is not valid Json.

Comment: check the edited question, the lat list contains the keyList..

Comment: You are saying the `keyList` are in the last item but what about the `key` values? Are they always in the first element of the list?

Comment: This is a list of json objects, if it includes 10 list then, 10th list contains keyList and overall Score only.. Rest are with same key value pairs.. And the keys are based on the keyList in the 10th list item.. if the keyList is "ABC,BVBV,NBN,MNM" then key value pairs are [{"ABC":100, "BVBV":200,"NBN":87,"MNM":09},{"ABC":1004, "BVBV":90,"NBN":847,"MNM":049},{"ABC":1040, "BVBV":2050,"NBN":867,"MNM":079},{"overallScore":10000,"keyList":"ABC,BVBV,NBN,MNM"}]

Comment: I think it is easier if you starts from the beginning and write a question with a full valid Json example and explaining what you want to extract from this Json. The last comment introduces multiple map objects with the same keys without explaining what value are are after. I am sure your problem makes completely sense for yourself but I am completely lost.

Comment: Question edited and added some examples.

Comment: You are still not explaining what you want. Your json examples contains multiple map objects with values. So what value do you want value1 to be when there are three maps which each have a key with the name e.g. "ABC"? Do you want to sum the result across the map objects or do you want each of them inside some data structure?

Comment: It is list mapping, ABC -> first element, etc. Question edited

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure this is what you want but here is my implementation:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final jsonEg1 = jsonDecode(eg1) as List<dynamic>;
  final keyListEg1 = parseKeyList(jsonEg1);

  print(keyListEg1);
  // [ABC, BVBV, NBN, MNM]

  print(parseElements(jsonEg1));
  // [[100, 200, 87, 9], [1004, 90, 847, 49], [1040, 2050, 867, 79]]

  final jsonEg2 = jsonDecode(eg2) as List<dynamic>;
  final keyListEg2 = parseKeyList(jsonEg2);

  print(keyListEg2);
  // [PQR, XYZ, POI, IOK, LOP, MLP]

  print(parseElements(jsonEg2));
  // [[100, 200, 87, 9, 890, 678], [1004, 90, 847, 49, 890, 678], [1040, 2050, 867, 79, 890, 678]]
}

List<String> parseKeyList(List<dynamic> json) =>
    ((json.last as Map<String, dynamic>)['keyList'] as String).split(',');

List<List<int>> parseElements(List<dynamic> json) {
  final result = json
      .take(json.length - 1)
      .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
      .map((data) => parseKeyList(json).map((key) => data[key] as int).toList())
      .toList();

  return result;
}

const String eg1 = '''
[
 {"ABC":100, "BVBV":200,"NBN":87,"MNM":9},
 {"ABC":1004, "BVBV":90,"NBN":847,"MNM":49},
 {"ABC":1040, "BVBV":2050,"NBN":867,"MNM":79},

 {"overallScore":10000,"keyList":"ABC,BVBV,NBN,MNM"}
]
''';

const String eg2 = '''
 [
 {"PQR":100, "XYZ":200,"POI":87,"IOK":9,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},
 {"PQR":1004, "XYZ":90,"POI":847,"IOK":49,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},
 {"PQR":1040, "XYZ":2050,"POI":867,"IOK":79,"LOP":890,"MLP":678},

 {"overallScore":10000,"keyList":"PQR,XYZ,POI,IOK,LOP,MLP"}
]
''';
```

The data structure of the result are not as you have described in your question but that is because it does make very little sense to do that since that cannot scale efficient and the number of values are dynamic.

Instead, the result are represented in a `List<List<int>>` structure so first result second value can e.g. be extracted as `parsedElementsEg2[0][1]` and makes it also easier to loop through the values;